# Outputting Stripe plan name via plan-ID using AngularJS ng-model two-way data binding

Tags: angularjs, laravel, stripe-payments

I am outputting form inputs on the final page of a checkout field, titled "Review & checkout"... on this page I display the plan the customer picked and the personal info they provided so far.

I have no problem showing fields like Name or Email, as the value inputted is being shown, as Angular displays whatever was in the value="" field of the input.

To display the subscription plan that the customer picked, it's trickier.

The value field is already being utilized to tell stripe which plan the customer should be charged for.

How can I get around this problem?

I am able to display the stripe-id for the plan but it is not user-friendly. They are id's like trad-2-5, trad-2-6, trad-2-7... so what I want to do is display a custom title when trad-2-5 is selected, and so on...

Any help is greatly appreciated!!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

The really silly answer is that you can just create a map of plan ids to human-readable descriptions in the Angular controller code, then display that. This might be enough for what you want, but it's also pretty hacky, and not a lot of fun to maintain.

The less silly answer depends on where these plan ids are coming from. If they are coming from an endpoint on your server, which gets them from Stripe's plans endpoint, then you could also pass along the display name of the plan from that endpoint. If the plan id's are hard coded somewhere, or whitelisted, then this may not make sense. However, that display name is what will appear on the customer's invoice, and credit card statement, so it'd be nice to make it match up with what they see on the checkout page.

Comment: There are 36 plans.. lots of plans but I still think the angular hacky version would be ideal... is there an example you can provide? I've never done that sort of thing